# Flow Router Footer Flashes to Top Before Data Loads

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I'm loading a grid of data with flow router, but when I view the page the footer always flashes to the top before the data loads. What is the best way to fix this?

Here is the route:

```
AdminRoutes.route('/dashboard', {
  name: 'adminDashboard',
  action() {
    BlazeLayout.render('AppLayout', {page: 'AdminDashboard'});
  }
});
```

Here is the js file:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating'
import Stores from '../../../../api/stores/stores.js'

import './AdminDashboard.html'

Template.AdminDashboard.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
    self.subscribe('stores.names.links');
  });
});

Template.AdminDashboard.helpers({
  stores: function () {
    return Stores.find();
  }
});
```

Here is the html layout file:

```
<template name='AppLayout'>

  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}

    {{> Header }}

    {{> Template.dynamic template=page}}

    {{> Footer }}

  {{/if}}

</template>
```

Here is the dashboard html file:

```
<template name='AdminDashboard'>
  <div class='admin-dashboard-page'>

    <section class='stores-grid'>
      {{#each stores}}
        <div class='store'>
          <h2 class='store-name'>{{name}}</h2>
          <a href='/admin/dashboard/{{link}}' class='store-button'>Edit</a>
        </div>
      {{/each}}
    </section>

  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try displaying the footer AFTER `.stores-grid` loads. Create a reactiveVar with a handler that is set to `true` when your data is loaded and return it's value on a helper, then wrap the footer in an `if` block on your template.

It would be something like the following...

First create a reactiveVar with a value of false:

```
Template.AdminDashboard.onCreated(function() {
  this.isDataLoaded = new ReactiveVar(false);
  var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
  self.subscribe('stores.names.links');
  });
});
```

Set the value to `true` when the collection is loaded:

```
Template.AdminDashboard.helpers({
  stores: function () {
    let data = Stores.find() 
    if(data) {
        Template.Instance().isDataLoaded.set(true)
      }
    return data ;
  },  

  dataLoaded: function () {
    return Template.Instance().isDataLoaded.get();
  }
});
```

Finally, wrap your footer so it's only displayed after data is loaded:

```
<template name='AppLayout'>
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{> Header }}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=page}}
    {{#if dataLoaded}}
        {{> Footer }}
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: Edited first answer, hope it helps!

Comment: It looks like the footer is no longer displaying at all and the Template.Instance needs to be Template.instance to not get errors in the first place

Comment: I believe the problem is that the AdminDashboard file is in the imports directory maybe..

Comment: I just wrote this from memory, no testing...  Have you tried adding the footer directly into the `AdminDashboard`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to set a minimum height on the `div` your content will be loaded into, pushing the footer down while the content loads. This may or may not work for you, depending on what the expected height of your content will be.

You could also install a loading screen/animation to hide the footer while the data loads.